# context.openFileInput() returning null when trying to access a stored file

Tags: android, android-file

Currently, I have the following code for saving a Web Archive and then getting it as a FileInputStream. However, the channel within webContent remains null and a FileNotFoundException is thrown:

```
        // Save the Web Archive once loading is finished
        String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + WEB_PREFIX + postId;
        webView.saveWebArchive(path);
        FileInputStream webContent = null;
        try {
            webContent = context.openFileInput(WEB_PREFIX + postId);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("onPageFinished()", "FileNotFoundException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If I try to perform context.openFileInput(path) instead, I get

```
09-05 23:39:42.448: E/AndroidRuntime(8399): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/data/com.example/files/web-2189241737372651547 contains a path separator
```

Does anyone know of a solution? The file certainly exists, since I saved it in the previous line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openFileInput()` doesn't accept paths, only a file name if you want to access a path.

Use this instead:

```
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + (WEB_PREFIX + postId));
```

**EDIT:**
You need to make sure you are saving and retrieving the file from the same place. Give this a go:

**Note:** I'm not sure you need  `File.separator` but try with and without it and see which one works.

```
 String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + WEB_PREFIX + postId;
        webView.saveWebArchive(path);
        FileInputStream webContent = null;
        try {
            webContent = new File(path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("onPageFinished()", "FileNotFoundException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that and "webContent = new FileInputStream(path);", however they both give a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: I tried your edit. The File is not null (which is great!) and the path is the same as the path specified in the string. I also checked adb and confirmed that the file was actually there (it was!). The only question left is why "webContent = new FileInputStream(path);" isn't working when File is.

Comment: Never mind, it's working now. "webContent = new FileInputStream(path);" fixed everything. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: By the way, webContent was the FileInputStream of the WebArchive.