# openFileInput always returning null

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm writing a string to a file using the method saveData();

```
public void saveData(){

    String fileName = "lifeClockSavedData";


 String birthYear = "1986";


    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);

      fileOutputStream.write(birthYear.getBytes());


        fileOutputStream.close();



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

And opening it in a widget activity using retrieve();

```
String messageString;

public void retrieve(Context context){


    String fileName = "lifeClockSavedData";



    try {
        String message;

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput(fileName);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null);{stringBuffer.append(message);}

        messageString =  stringBuffer.toString();



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

As far as I can tell, this should set messageString to "1986", but the value is always "null".

I'd appreciate a pointer as to what's going wrong.

edit: This question isn't a duplicate of [context.openFileInput() returning null when trying to access a stored file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649543/context-openfileinput-returning-null-when-trying-to-access-a-stored-file)

as I'm not trying to get openFileInput() to accept a path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [context.openFileInput() returning null when trying to access a stored file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649543/context-openfileinput-returning-null-when-trying-to-access-a-stored-file)

Comment: `while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null);` <-- Notice that semicolon right there. You sure your IDE didn't give you a warning about that? Something about an empty statement?

Comment: Mike M - I did not notice that semicolon. Makes sense, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm writing a string to a file

No, you are not. You are writing bytes to file.

Either:

- Write a string to the file (e.g., via a `PrintWriter` wrapped around an `OutputStreamWriter`), or
- Read bytes from the file, then construct a `String` from those bytes

Answer (score 0):

scrapped:

```
while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null);{stringBuffer.append(message);}
```

replaced with:

```
stringBuffer.append(bufferedReader.readLine());
```

Not sure why it worked, as bufferedReader.readline() wasn't null.